# Overwrite dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm making a dataframe in R.
With this code I'm currently making a dataframe with 1 row.

```
logs_data_frame <- data.frame(
      session_id = 1,
      t_minus = NA,
      glucose_reading = NA,
      activity_type = "test",
      duration = "test2",
      intensity = "test3",
      activity_start = "test4",
      bolus_taken = NA,
      bolus_3hr = NA,
      previous_flow = NA,
      new_flow_number = NA,
      action_bolus = NA,
      action_basaal = NA,
      action_carbs = NA,
      recommendation_bolus = NA,
      recommendation_basaal = NA,
      recommendation_carbs = NA,
      bolus_1hr = NA,
      date = Sys.Date(),
      pid = 2
    )
```

Now I'm wondering how to overwrite some values like t_minus and Glucose_reading so that instead of NA they have test 5 and 6 without making another row

Kind regards and thanks for the help!

Comment: `logs_data_frame$t_minus <- "test 5"`?

Comment: Thanks! Let's say that I have 4 rows, How do I only change this T_minus column in the 3rd row?

Comment: `logs_data_frame[3, "t_minus"] <- "test 5"`